# Не получается установить вебхук(viber)

Tags: python, post, curl, viber

Следовал инструкции с офф.сайта

Вот views.py файлик

```
@csrf_exempt
def botviber(request):
    bot_configuration = BotConfiguration(
        name='zxcasdqwezxcasdqwe',
        avatar='http://viber.com/avatar.jpg',
        auth_token='************************'
    )

    viber = Api(bot_configuration)
    viber.set_webhook('https://sitename.ninja/botviber/')

    viber_request = viber.parse_request(request.get_data())
    print(viber_request)
```

После этого при попытке перейти на сайт - получаю вот такую ошибку:

```
Exception at /botviber/
failed with status: 1, message: Result[HttpRequest[POST /botviber/ HTTP/1.1]@533b70c > HttpResponse[null 0 null]@28581fb9] java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Total timeout elapsed
```

Забил на это, решил через curl сделать вебхук

Вот команда `curl -# -i -g -H "X-Viber-Auth-Token:*****" -d @vibe.json -X POST https://chatapi.viber.com/pa/set_webhook -v`

Cам vibe.json файл

```
{
  "url": "https://sitename.ninja"
}
```

Тоже ошибка -

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 52.4.209.25...
* Connected to chatapi.viber.com (52.4.209.25) port 443 (#0)
* found 148 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 594 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*    server certificate verification OK
*    server certificate status verification SKIPPED
*    common name: *.viber.com (matched)
*    server certificate expiration date OK
*    server certificate activation date OK
*    certificate public key: RSA
*    certificate version: #3
*    subject: C=LU,ST=Luxembourg,L=Luxembourg,O=Viber Media Sarl,OU=IT,CN=*.viber.com
*    start date: Sun, 26 Jun 2016 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: Tue, 26 Jun 2018 23:59:59 GMT
*    issuer: C=US,O=thawte\, Inc.,CN=thawte SSL CA - G2
*    compression: NULL
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
> POST /pa/set_webhook HTTP/1.1
> Host: chatapi.viber.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> X-Viber-Auth-Token:security
> Content-Length: 39
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 39 out of 39 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< cache-control: no-cache no-store
cache-control: no-cache no-store
< content-type: application/json
content-type: application/json
< date: Sat Feb 10 21:03:46 2018
date: Sat Feb 10 21:03:46 2018
< Content-Length: 158
Content-Length: 158
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive

< 
* Connection #0 to host chatapi.viber.com left intact
{"status":1,"status_message":"Result[HttpRequest[POST / HTTP/1.1]@40da913d > HttpResponse[null 0 null]@c0d645f] java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressEx
```

Помогите пожалуйста, в чем здесь вообще ошибка и как быть

Comment: `ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol`

Comment: @AndrioSkur я добавил в настройках nginx, там гдe 443 порт - http2. К сожалению ошибка не исчезла

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка решилась. В json файле с адресом оказалась 1 русская буква.